Flutter desktop app flickers on Windows 7 launch
I'm developing a desktop app using Flutter and I've encountered an issue specifically on Windows 7. When launching the app on Windows 8, 10, and 11, everything works fine without any flickering. However, on Windows 7, there's a noticeable flicker just before the app fully launches.
I've tried debugging and searching for solutions, but haven't been able to find a fix yet. Has anyone else experienced this issue with Flutter desktop apps on Windows 7? And if so, are there any known workarounds or solutions to mitigate this flickering?
Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
